# Cannot find name 'Map', 'Set', 'Symbol', 'WeakMap', 'WeakSet'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

This is a new Angular 6 project.
All dependencies are up-to-date.

**Error output**

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./src/vendors.ts 5560:15-36 6:0-24

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./src/vendors.ts 5572:15-102 6:0-24

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts:87:123 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts:87:165 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:82:59 
    TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/keyvalue_differs.d.ts:22:18 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:24:16 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:32:16 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts:48:34 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:351:20 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:353:28 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:355:15 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:357:23 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:359:17 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:361:25 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts:555:63 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.d.ts:71:61 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.d.ts:77:89 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/type_check_compiler.d.ts:30:161 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts:87:32 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts:52:71 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/http/src/url_search_params.d.ts:46:16 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts:97:42 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts:79:33 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts:11:30 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts:22:30 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/router/src/router_outlet_context.d.ts:42:28 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/router/src/router_outlet_context.d.ts:43:34 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:6208:55 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:6215:55 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:6219:64 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:6225:59 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:6226:59 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakSet'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/app.component.ts:8:14 
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/app.module.ts:17:14 
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

**Major DevDependencies**

- @angular/* `6.0.3`
- @types/node `10.1.2`
- @types/core-js `0.9.46`
- typescript `2.8.3`
- webpack `4.9.1`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6",
            "es7",
            "dom"
        ],
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "core-js",
            "node"
        ],
        "include": [
            "src/**/*"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules"
    ]
}
```

---

**Dead ends**

- Changing the target to `es5`, `es2015`, `es6`, `es2016`
- Removing from tsconfig `typeRoots`, `types`, `include`, `exclude`
- Changing `./node_modules` to `node_modules` from tsconfig `typeRoots` and `exclude`
- Removing `node_modules` folder and `npm cache` then reinstalling all dependencies with `yarn install`

**I know that this is a frequently asked question nevertheless I did not find any solution to my problem.**

Thanks for the help !

Comment: This behaviour is specific to `lib` option, which is already specified, so it should work as intended and it's unclear what the problem is. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem - a stackblitz, repo, etc.

Comment: The current project with these errors is accessible on [GitHub](https://github.com/C0ZEN/webpack-angular). Master branch, tag 0.1.0.

Comment: Install the dependencies with `yarn install` then run `npm run build` to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before all, I want to thank **@estus** for his answer.
It does not solve the problem despite that he pointed out the right problem.

Indeed, the change below does not fix the problem.

> helpers.root('.', 'tsconfig.json')

I was not thinking at all that the problem could have been a configuration in my webpack file but it was.
Checkout the changes that I made to fix this:

**Change the _root path from helpers.js**

```
// Removed the second argument .. from the resolve
const _root = path.resolve(__dirname);
```

**Change each call of helpers.root from the webpack config**

```
// Instead of helpers.root('./src')
helpers.root('src')

// Instead of helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json')
// Which was clearly wrong in all cases because it is not in src folder
helpers.root('tsconfig.json')
```

You can also checkout the tag [0.1.1](https://github.com/C0ZEN/webpack-angular/releases/tag/0.1.1) with the fix or checkout the [changes](https://github.com/C0ZEN/webpack-angular/commit/9247cb8336a913ef5e869ee5ea3175fb05e67b52).

Answer (score 2):

ES6 typings can be provided either by polyfill (`core-js`) or by TypeScript itself (this is what `lib` compiler option is responsible for). Since relevant libraries were provided in `lib` (`es6`), it's expected that ES6 features are recognized by TypeScript.

Webpack configuration sets wrong path to tsconfig.json:

```
        {
            test   : /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [

                // Parse TypeScript to JavaScript
                {
                    loader : 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: {
                        configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json')
                    }
                },

                // Add require(...) as prefix for templateUrl and styleUrls in Angular components
                // This way allow the loader to inject external files as inline data
                'angular2-template-loader'
            ]
        },
```

So TypeScript configuration isn't picked up.

It should be:

```
helpers.root('.', 'tsconfig.json')
```

Comment: Thank you @estus, you are awesome. You are right when pointing the error but your answer does not solve my issue. I found out the solution and comment my own answer to be more explicit on how I fixed it.Have a good day.

Comment: I've checked that this works before posting it. Not sure why this didn't work for you, possibly because this has something to do with current working directory or else, I didn't check how helpers.root works. Any way, not loading tsconfig is a common problem, hope this question will help somebody else.